# how to run insertAdjacentElement() function javascript on Chrome, Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'm using javascript with some functions in jsp file, when I run on IE, it run good, but run with Chrome or FF, it seem not run.

this is my file:

```
<script>
function adds(index, values)
{   
if(values.replace(/\s/g, "") == "") {
    alert("Enter the answer and click 'Add' button.");

    return;
}

var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options");
var opt=document.createElement("option");    
opt.value = opts.length + 1;
opt.innerText = values;
opts.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd",opt);

eval("frm.ans" + index + ".value = '' ");

setting_val(index);
}
function up_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options");

for (var i=0; i<opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i>0) {
        tmp=opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        opts[i].removeNode(true);
        opts[i-1].insertAdjacentElement("beforeBegin",tmp).selected=true;
    }
}

setting_val(index);
}

function down_move(index)
{
var frm = document.writeForm;
var opts=eval("frm.ans_list" + index + ".options");

for (var i=opts.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (opts[i].selected && i<opts.length-1) {
        tmp=opts[i].cloneNode(true);
        opts[i].removeNode(true);
        opts[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd",tmp).selected=true;
    }
}

setting_val(index);
}
</script>

<body>
   <a href="#" onClick="return adds('<%=i+1%>',document.writeForm.ans<%=i+1%>.value);" style="float:left"><span class="bt_test_admin bg_type_01">Add</span></a>
 </body>
```

Debug on Chrome and FF:

```
**TypeError: opts.insertAdjacentElement is not a function**
```

I have search a lot of ways but I don't understand why, How to fix this error and run on Chrome and FF?

thanks so much !!

Comment: Please don't abuse `eval()` like this. The following works without needing to use it: `frm['ans_list' + index].options`.

Comment: Why the f**k is there a JAVA tag? :D

Comment: Hi @Phylogenesis: your meaning is no need to use eval() ? could you tell me detail ?

Comment: Yes. For instance, you can use `frm['ans' + index].value = '';` instead of `eval("frm.ans" + index + "value = '' ");`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: I have try and it same error..

Comment: it still get an errror: TypeError: opts.insertAdjacentElement is not a function

Comment: That's because it won't fix that issue. I raised a different issue with your code. If you find that you're using `eval()`, you are *almost certainly* doing something wrong.

Comment: Your actual issue is that you are using `opts.insertAdjacentElement()`. In this case `opts` is not a single element, so it does not have that function available. Maybe you need something like `opts[opts.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', opt)`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis: yes I see, I'm try with: opts[opts.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', opt)

Comment: Hi @Phylogenesis: it still same error :(

Comment: What about `frm['ans_list' + index].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', opt);` or `frm['ans_list' + index].appendChild(opt);`?

Comment: Hi @Phylogenesis: I use: frm['ans_list' + index].appendChild(opt);, it worked ^^, thank you so much !!